# How to change the this in the Controller as construction

Tags: angularjs, this, angular-promise

I'm trying to use the Controller as structure in AngularJS. 
For this to work I use the this of the controller to store the value show in the form.

In the controller the values are set by a promise. The promise then has it's own this which is not equal to the Controller, so I change the this by using the angular.bind(this, function() {}) construction. T

But if I change something like this.contact in the promise then function the this.contact of the Controller will not change. How do I change that value of the this?

Example:

```
angular.module('starter')
  .controller('ContactViewController', function($scope, $log, Address) {
    this.contact = {
      type: 'contact'
    };


    Address.get(1).then(angular.bind(this, function(rec) {
      $log.log('rec:',rec);
      this.contact = rec;     // does NOT work
    }));

    $scope.$on('contact.create', angular.bind(this, function(event, contact) {
      this.contact = contact; // this DOES work
    }));
  }); 


angular.module('starter')
  .factory('Address', ['$q', '$rootScope', function($q, $rootScope) {
      get : function(id) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        localDB.get(id, function (err, doc) {
            if (err) {
              deferred.reject(err);
            } else {
              $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                deferred.resolve(doc);
              });
            }
          });
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    }
  }]);
```

Comment: Seems like you may have a syntax error in the posted code. Missing the closing `)` of bind function `Address.get(1).then(angular.bind(this, function(rec) {
         $log.log('rec:', rec);
         this.contact = rec;
       }));`

Comment: Have you verified that `$log.log('rec:', rec);` is logging the expected value and that it is in the format that it needs to be?

Comment: There's also a typo in your factory. I believe you're missing a `return {` at the top of your factory function.

Comment: I've set up a jsfiddle here that (I think) captures the heart of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/x77t8L1h/

It seems to work just fine. Is there something about `localDB.get` that I'm not capturing correctly?

Comment: Thanks for making the jsfiddle. Should have done that my self. It help a lot finding the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. It does work as expected. The this of the promise is changed to the one that is in the scope of the controller.

The error was in the view connected that did not reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

`this` changes with context, and has a different value inside the promise function closure.

It is generally recommended by the community to capture the value of `this` into a variable in the beginning of your controller:

- https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide/blob/master/README.md#controllers
- https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide/blob/master/README.md#style-y032